# How to play PACMAN in terminal?

Tags: games

Is there some cli software or script for running pacman in terminal?. It is helpful i am looking for just-simple-pacman without huge graphics or somthing that used lot of resources through wine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want a *pure* console version (something you could play over SSH, for example), try `pacman4console` (`sudo apt-get install pacman4console`). It's pretty ugly but it works.

[image]

But I don't think it's the best. I personally prefer `pacman` (`sudo apt-get install pacman`), mostly because it looks like the original Pacman game... But it's graphical. I don't understand why that's neccessarily a *bad* thing so I'm including it.

[image]

There are a couple of other graphical clones in the (`njam` which has multiplayer, and `hannah`) and there are several as part of compilations (`gtkboard` and `childsplay` both have Pacman clones).

Comment: Because some people only have a server to play on >:D

Comment: Pity none of these seem to have sound... +1

Answer (score 1):

There is one called myman you can download from Sourceforge and you have to compile it from source. It hasn't been updated since 2009 but it still works.

First, install the dependencies:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libncurses5-dev groff build-essential
```

Next, extract the files and cd into the extracted directory:

```
tar xvfvz myman-wip-2009-10-30.tar.gz
cd myman-wip-2009-10-30
```

Finally, compile, install, and run:

<sub>NOTE: if you don't want to install system wide, do not run `sudo make install` and see the instructions below instead</sub>

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
myman
```

If you do not want to install system wide, you can use these instructions instead:

```
./configure
make
mkdir ~/bin
cp myman ~/bin
. ~/.profile
myman
```

Of course, the `myman` command runs the game.

Also, it runs on ncurses so if you have trouble rendering over ssh, run `screen` or `tmux` before you run the `myman` command.

[image: screenshot of the myman pacmanlike ncurses game]

[image: another screenshot of the myman game]

---

**HELPFUL OPTIONS:**

`-2` - wide screen

`-b` - enable sounds

`-o` - use 'o' for power pellets and bullet for dots

Comment: The screenshots are via SSH into Ubuntu using an Android device (external keyboard attached).